# WPF запретить доступ к кнопке если один из textbox пустой

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

У меня на окне 36 textBox, как адекватно сделать запрет к кнопке если хоть одно поле пустое? Каждый textBox подписываеться на параметры свойства:

```
    private Mark selectedMark;
    public Mark SelectedMark
    {
        get { return selectedMark; }
        set
        {
            selectedMark = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMark");
        }
    }
```

Подписываюсь к параметрам так

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedMark.OC1}" />
```

Comment: Команду заведите для кнопки и в сеттерах свойств, привязанных к TextBox'ам, вызывайте CanExecuteChanged той команды. А CanExecute пусть проверяет типа `.All(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))`

Comment: @Андрей а если у меня только одно свойство и это класс, а textBox привязываються к параметрам этого класса. Как мне тогда CanExecuteChanged вызывать в этих параметрах?

Comment: Лучше определите одно свойство - `IsValid`, которое свяжите с `IsEnabled` для button

Comment: не уверен, что понимаю, зачем может понадобиться сразу 36 свойств в одном классе

Comment: @FoggyFinder ох... их всего 42, но мне нужно проверить 36, а вобще это строка из таблицы

Comment: @MaximKoylo, подробнее опишите, приведите код VM

Comment: Читайте про валидацию wpf, в вашем случае для упрощения можно использовать рефлексию и атрибуты

Comment: @MaximKoylo у вас в таблице 42 столбца?

Comment: @FoggyFinder я понимаю что это дико звучит, это таблица различных 
 оценок (оценки по тестам). Пишу программу для аттестации операторов верстатов ЧПУ

Comment: 36 полей в одном окне - это дикий ужас с точки зрения будущего пользователя вашей программы. Сделайте кнопки вперед/назад и сделайте по 5-7 текстбоксов максимум в одном окне.

Comment: @Bulson Я продумал интерфейс и там все очень красиво и пользывателю никак не мешает

Comment: Над теорией UX/UI размышляли/ют не самые глупые люди. Базовые требования к интерфейсу программ есть в любой книге на эту тему. Средний человек способен воспринимать и контролировать за раз довольно ограниченное число переменных, 36 явно больше возможностей любого человека.

Comment: @Bulson У меня тест разделен на три составляющие, соответственно в робочей зоне 12 текстовых полей (6 вопросов, одно поле для того кто отвечает и одно для того кто проверяет)

Comment: Для включения кнопки можно попробовать создать класс, кот. будет подписан на события потери фокуса текстбоксами. В этом классе создать поле типа массива булевых, при наступлении события потери фокуса выясняем индекс текстбокса и отмечаем `true` у нужного элемента массива. Затем выясняем с пом. `All(e => e == true)` и если так, то вызываем событие заполненности всех текстбоксов, и по нему включаем кнопку.

Comment: @Bulson спсибо, сделаю по вашему

Comment: P.S. в обработчике события потери фокуса нужно выяснять заполнен текстбокс или нет, соответственно true или false устанавливать у нужного элемента массива.

Comment: Что это за 36 текстбоксов? Позволено их разместить в массиве и рендерить через `ItemsControl`?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил Вам завести bool переменную, равную && всех значений в textBox.
Т.е. проверять каждый textBox и через && добавлять значение выражения (text == "") к этой переменной.

А доступ соответственно подвесить на true этой переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Пример с использованием атрибутов и рефлексии.

Есть базовый класс для VM:

```
abstract class Vm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected virtual bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;
        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

наследуем от него класс поддерживающий валидацию:

```
abstract class ValidatableVm : Vm
{
    protected override bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var b = base.Set(ref field, value, propertyName);
        if (b && GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), true).Length > 0)
        {
            IsValid = GetType().GetProperties()
                               .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), true).Length > 0)
                               .Select(p => (string)p.GetValue(this))
                               .All(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
        }
        return b;
    }

    public bool IsValid { get; private set; }
}
```

Здесь в методе `Set` если произошло обновление свойства, то для текущего типа VM берем все свойства помеченные атрибутом и проверяем чтобы они были не пусты.
Я использовал атрибут `Required` из пространства имен `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, если вам это не подходит - вы можете создать свой атрибут.

Пример использования, VM:

```
class MainVM : ValidatableVm
{
    string name;
    [Required]
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => Set(ref name, value);
    }

    string address;
    [Required]
    public string Address
    {
        get => address;
        set => Set(ref address, value);
    }

    string phone;
    public string Phone
    {
        get => phone;
        set => Set(ref phone, value);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, атрибутом помечены только 2 свойства, именно они и будут проверяться на непустоту.

Разметка:

```
<StackPanel Margin="5">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Address, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Phone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <Button Content="Click me" IsEnabled="{Binding IsValid}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: К сожалению не совсем подходит, для простых свойств работает прекрасно, а как быть с полями класса. В классе ValidatableVM в строке .Select(p => (string)p.GetValue(this)) производиться приведение к string, а мне нужно к полям класса Mark, как их указать в этом запросе?

Comment: Если я так сделаю это будет нормально? .Select(p => (Models.Mark)p.GetValue(this))
                                   .All(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.OE1) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.OE2) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.OE3) /* и т.д 34 разв */);

Comment: Нет, конечно, здесь рефлексия для этого и применяется чтоб 40 раз одно и то же не писать. Сам `Mark` наследуйте от `ValidatableVm`

Comment: Унаследовал но всеравно пишет что нельза привести к типу string

Comment: На каком свойстве спотыкается?

Comment: просто пишет что не может привести, у меня в класе Mark два поля int, может из-за них? Если да то как их не учитывать

Comment: Просто не помечайте их атрибутом, они ведь и так пустыми не будут

Comment: Что то я забыл что можно просто linq програть по всем полям на пустоту, всего то одна строчка...

Comment: @MaximKoylo, получилось что-нибудь?

Comment: По мне так вы сильно усложнили решение...

Comment: @AGS17, опубликуете свое решение?

Comment: @Андрей если сегодня время найду, думаю, что да.